# When should I define a new TensorFlow op?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

For my application, I was able to create a new function using only predefined ops. Is there any need to define a new op in this case?

The pseudocode for my function is:

```
z1 = myGauss(arg, arg2)

def myGauss(arg, arg2):
  # Here I only used defined tensorflow operations
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can achieve what you set out to do with a composition of existing ops, then that's great! You **don't** need to create a new op.

There are circumstances when we've found it necessary to create a new op, however:

- Sometimes you can gain performance by *fusing* ops together into a single op. For example many of the ["training" ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc) have fused implementations, even though they were initially implemented using simple ops.
- Another example is when you want to define a gradient for a composition of ops (because it's more efficient or stable to consider the expression as a whole). This is the rationale for ops like [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

Comment: Do you have any comments on using [tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, name=None)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/script_ops.html#py_func)  for say defining a new layer or loss function? I mainly ask since the indexing in v0.6.0 was unsupported.